# Temperature at which to pickle herrings

Tags: temperature, pickling, herring

If the pickling process takes approximately  2-3 days, should the pickling process take place at room temperature? Or can it be done in a refrigerator?

Answer (score 3):

Herrings *should* be pickled in refrigerator. Before the pickling solution fully infuses the fish, there's little to prevent its spoilage - and depending on strength of the solution and size (thickness) of pieces of fish, if the process is fast enough, that's non-issue, but if it's to take 2-3 days in room temperatures, you may end up with pickled fish that's spoiled inside.